# Player's name on uniform: when and why did it start?

Tags: equipment, trivia

Which competition (or team, if relevant) was the first to print each player's name on the uniform? Was there a specific reason given to do so?

Both questions are independent of specific sports. The first one I'm asking out of historical interest. The second is because I see little point in printing players' names when they already have identifying numbers (other than selling replica uniforms, which is, as far as I know, a practice that postdates the introduction of named uniforms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which competition (or team, if relevant) was the first to print each player's name on the uniform?

Bill Veeck, owner of MLB's Chicago White Sox, pioneered the idea to add names on jerseys in 1960.

> Was there a specific reason given to do so?

The names were distinguishable when broadcast on television.

More on the history of names on jerseys can be found [here](http://espn.go.com/espn/page2/story?page=lukas/041202).